# Removing signed kernel installs unsigned kernel

Tags: apt, kernel, 22.04

I have tried removing the 5.17.0-1014 kernel with the command:

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-5.17.0-1014-oem
```

And apt suggests to install linux-image-unsigned-5.17.0-1014-oem.

To remove the kernel I have typed the command:

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-5.17.0-1014-oem linux-image-unsigned-5.17.0-1014-oem
```

Is it normal behavior of apt?

Answer (score 2):

I've found similar older question [Removing linux-image kernel causes linux-image-unsigned package to be installed](https://askubuntu.com/q/1170575/764841)

I like answer from @t7e https://askubuntu.com/a/1418845/764841 it worked for me.

> It seemed not obvious, but quite a simple solution - just remove them both in one command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic linux-image-unsigned-4.18.0-15-generic
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed by system update. It works normally presently.

```
sudo apt remove linux-image
sudo apt remove linux-modules
sudo apt remove linux-headers
```