# Can't purge old kernels

Tags: package-management, kernel, disk-usage

I have ubuntu 20.04. I have been having problems with the /boot folder running out of space.

```
$ sudo apt list --installed | grep linux-image

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.11.0-40-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.11.0-43-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-43.47~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.11.0-44-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-44.48~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.13.0-25.26~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.13.0-28-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.13.0-35-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.13.0-35.40~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.13.0-37-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.13.0-37.42~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.13.0-48-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.13.0-48.54~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.13.0-51-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.13.0-51.58~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.13.0-52-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.13.0-52.59~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-41-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-41.44~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-43.46~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-46.49~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-48.54~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-50.56~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-52-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-52.58~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-53-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-53.59~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-56.62~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-57-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-57.63~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-58-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-58.64~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-67-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-67.74~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-69-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-69.76~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-71-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-71.78~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-79-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-79.86~20.04.2 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-82-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-82.91~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-84-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-84.93~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-87-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-87.97~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-88-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-88.98~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.15.0-91-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-91.101~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.8.0-59-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.8.0-59.66~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.8.0-63-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.8.0-63.71~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0.91.101~20.04.48 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-27-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-34-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-34.36~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-36-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-36.40~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-37-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-37.41~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-39-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.13.0-39.44~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-40-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.13.0-40.45~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-41-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.13.0-41.46~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-44-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.13.0-44.49~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-70-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-70.77~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-72-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-72.79~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-73-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-73.80~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-86-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0-86.96~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

/boot folder contents:

```
$ ls -l /boot
total 342408
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    262258 Aug 18 10:34 config-5.15.0-82-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    262265 Nov 16 08:58 config-5.15.0-91-generic
drwx------ 3 root root      4096 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root      4096 Dec 14 11:32 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 129102715 Sep 19 07:56 initrd.img-5.15.0-82-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  55717600 Dec 14 11:30 initrd.img-5.15.0-86-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 129129902 Dec 14 10:45 initrd.img-5.15.0-91-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        28 Dec 14 11:30 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.15.0-91-generic
drwx------ 2 root root     16384 Jun  9  2021 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    182704 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    184380 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    184884 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root   6240491 Aug 18 10:34 System.map-5.15.0-82-generic
-rw------- 1 root root   6242483 Nov 16 08:58 System.map-5.15.0-91-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        25 Dec 14 11:30 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.11.0-25-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  11522568 Aug 18 12:03 vmlinuz-5.15.0-82-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  11517416 Nov 16 09:01 vmlinuz-5.15.0-91-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        25 Dec 14 11:30 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.15.0-91-generic
```

If I run:

```
sudo apt remove --purge linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-25-generic
```

I get:

```
$ sudo apt remove --purge linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-25-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-modules-5.11.0-25-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.11.0-25-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                            linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-25-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-25-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.11.0-25-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-25-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-signatures-nvidia-5.11.0-25-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.11.0-25-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                      linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-25-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I then run the command it suggests:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

It shows (moving to pastebin to free up characters):

```
https://pastebin.com/FmpseWKi
```

/boot partition size

```
$ df -h | grep boot
/dev/nvme0n1p2             704M  343M  310M  53% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1             511M   87M  425M  17% /boot/efi
```

I don't know how to purge these old kernels and how to keep the /boot folder from filling up.

**UPDATE**
I tried using Synaptic as user68186 suggested (and also was suggested in the links posted). When I tried to only uninstall *linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic*, it also wanted to install *linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-25-generic*. I read here [Removing linux-image kernel causes linux-image-unsigned package to be installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170575/removing-linux-image-kernel-causes-linux-image-unsigned-package-to-be-installed)  that this is because I need to also remove the corresponding *modules* package. I selected *linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-25-generic* and *linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic*, and This is what I got:

```
(Reading database ... 2036888 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-signatures-nvidia-5.13.0-25-generic (5.13.0-25.26~20.04.1+1) ...
Removing linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-25-generic (5.13.0-25.26~20.04.1) ...
Removing linux-modules-5.13.0-25-generic (5.13.0-25.26~20.04.1) ...
Removing linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic (5.13.0-25.26~20.04.1) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.15.0-82-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.15.0-82-generic
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.15.0-91-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.15.0-91-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-25-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-91-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-91-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-82-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-82-generic
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-36-generic (5.11.0-36.40~20.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.13.0-48-generic (5.13.0-48.54~20.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-73-generic (5.15.0-73.80~20.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-39-generic (5.13.0-39.44~20.04.1) ...
(Reading database ... 2029733 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for linux-modules-5.13.0-25-generic (5.13.0-25.26~20.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.13.0-48-generic (5.13.0-48.54~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.13.0-48-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-48-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-91-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-91-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-82-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-82-generic
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-73-generic (5.15.0-73.80~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.15.0-73-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-73-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-91-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-91-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-82-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-82-generic
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-39-generic (5.13.0-39.44~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.13.0-39-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-39-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-91-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-91-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-82-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-82-generic
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-36-generic (5.11.0-36.40~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.11.0-36-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-36-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-36-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-36-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-36-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-36-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-36-generic (5.11.0-36.40~20.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-36-generic (5.11.0-36.40~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.11.0-36-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-36-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
cpio: write error: Broken pipe
sort: write failed: 'standard output': Broken pipe
sort: write error
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 2 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-36-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-36-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-36-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-36-generic
```

Do you have any suggestions for what to do here?

**Update 2**

I ran

```
sudo apt autopurge
```

and got this (unfortunately it won't let me add anymore text to this question, so I had to put it in pastebin):

```
https://pastebin.com/wb00JM5y
```

**Update 3**

I was finally able to use Synaptic to remove the old kernels. For some reason it had a problem with 5.11.0-36 and 5.11.0-25. It was like I had to remove 36 first and then it let me remove 25. But after I got those removed, I could remove all the others with no errors.

Comment: I find it easier to use the GUI app called `Synaptic` to look up and remove old kernels. It will not fix the "Unmet dependencies" issue though.

Comment: See [this question and its answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406581/why-does-ubuntu-not-clean-out-old-kernel-module-files-in-lib-modules-when-old) for how to delete old kernels. Also see [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) Read all the answers, not just the top one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My /boot partition hit 100% and now I can't upgrade. Can't remove old kernels to make room](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to)

Comment: **Update 3** seems like the answer. Please don't put the answer inside the question in this Q&A site. Use the **Answer Your Own Question** button below and write a detailed answer. This will help others. Later you may accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the Synaptic Package Manager GUI to remove the old kernels. I initially had a problem with removing the 5.11.0-36 and 5.11.0-25 ones. I got errors unless I removed the 36 one first.

I found that if I selected the "linux-**modules**-<version>-generic" ones it would automatically select the other related packages and this cut down on the number of packages I had to select.

Answer (score 0):

Packages not used and necessary for the system any more can be removed with `sudo apt autoremove` or `sudo apt autopurge`. The latter will also delete configurations files (if the packages to be removed have any).

This will also remove all old kernels, the two newest ones will be automatically kept.

Comment: I ran it but got errors. Please see my Update 2 in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool on Launchpad called [`linux-purge`](https://launchpad.net/linux-purge) that cleans out old kernels easily.

These are the installation instructions:

> Run the following command chain in terminal to install linux-purge in
> your system:
>
> ```
> sh -c 'cd /tmp && wget -N https://git.launchpad.net/linux-purge/plain/install-linux-purge.sh && chmod +x ./install-linux-purge.sh && sudo ./install-linux-purge.sh && rm ./install-linux-purge.sh' && [ "$BASH" ] && echo Replaced current shell in order to make the Bash completion work. && exec bash
> ```
>
> You may be prompted for password because of use of sudo with the
> script.

After that, simply run it with `sudo linux-purge`, and it will by default remove everything except the two latest kernels.